# How to choose the window size of CNN in deep learning?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, data-science, hyperparameters

In Convolutional Neural Network (CNN), a filter is select for weights sharing. For example, in the following pictures, a 3x3 window with the stride (distance between adjacent neurons) 1 is chosen.

[image]

[image]

So my question is: **How to choose the window size?** If I use 4x4 with the stride being 2, how much difference will it cause? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's no definite answer to this: filter size is one of hyperparameters you generally need to tune. However, there're some useful observations, that may help you. It's often preferred to choose **smaller filters**, but have **greater number** of those.

Example: four `5x5` filters have 100 parameters (ignoring bias), while 10 `3x3` filters have 90 parameters. Through the larger of filters you still can capture the variety of features in the image, but with fewer parameters. More on this [here](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/#conv).

Modern CNNs go even further with this idea and choose consecutive `3x1` and `1x3` convolutional layers. This reduces the number of parameters even more, but doesn't affect the performance. See the [evolution of inception network](https://medium.com/towards-data-science/neural-network-architectures-156e5bad51ba).

The choice of stride is also important, but it affects the tensor shape after the convolution, hence the whole network. The general rule is to use `stride=1` in usual convolutions and preserve the spatial size with padding, and use `stride=2` when you want to downsample the image.

Comment: in my experience, downsampling is better achieved with maxpooling because the gradients are larger compared to strides (you may face gradient vanishing otherwise). Also, downsampling with strides is not selecting the interesting areas.